# Changing the CI for difflsmeans

Tags: r, confidence-interval, mixed-models

I am running a linear mixed model and using the function `diffslmeans()` from the `lmerTest` package to calculate pairwise differences in my fixed effects.

The function seems to produce 95% CI no matter what I try. I'd like to use 90% CI, however. I've tried `conf = 0.9`, `conf.int = 0.9`, and `conf = 90`.

Is it not possible to change the confidence level in this function?

Answer (score 0):

After examining the GitHub repository of this package ( https://github.com/cran/lmerTest/blob/master/R/generalFunctions.R ) I think the value of 95% CI is hardcoded into the `diffslmeans`. Here is the code of it:

```
difflsmeans <- function(model, test.effs=NULL, ddf = "Satterthwaite", ...)
{
  if(!inherits(model, "lmerMod"))
    stop("The model is not linear mixed effects model")

  ddf <- checkNameDDF(ddf)
  result <- lsmeans.calc(model, 0.05, test.effs = test.effs, 
                         lsmeansORdiff = FALSE, ddf)  
  res <- list(diffs.lsmeans.table=result$summ.data, 
              response=result$response)
  class(res) <- "difflsmeans"
  res 
}
```

The second parameter of `lsmeans.calc` is 0.05 which I assume stands for the significance level. You can look at https://github.com/cran/lmerTest/blob/master/R/lsmeans.R for further details.

The way to use variable CI is to create your one function with extra parameter `conf`, e.g. something like this:

```
difflsmeans_new <- function(model, test.effs=NULL,
                            ddf = "Satterthwaite",
                            conf = 0.95)
{
  if(!inherits(model, "lmerMod"))
    stop("The model is not linear mixed effects model")

  ddf <- checkNameDDF(ddf)
  result <- lsmeans.calc(model, 1-conf, test.effs = test.effs, 
                         lsmeansORdiff = FALSE, ddf)  
  res <- list(diffs.lsmeans.table=result$summ.data, 
              response=result$response)
  class(res) <- "difflsmeans"
  res 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Interesting that it is hard coded in. I tried out your new function and I get an error of: could not find function "checkNameDDF".

I tried to delete that line of code from the function to see what would happen and got: could not find function "lsmeans.calc"

Comment: Well then the simple method doesn't work. In that case you can look at the code on the GitHub page to copy all functions needed in order to make this new function work.

Comment: I'll try and parse through it. Thank you